# match (row) against ('text') wont return results

Tags: mysql

```
$qstring = "SELECT titulo as value, id FROM blogs WHERE titulo LIKE '%".$term."%'          LIMIT 5";
$qstring = "SELECT titulo as value, id FROM blogs WHERE MATCH(titulo) AGAINST ('.$term.')  LIMIT 5";
```

The first one will return results but not really related to the query

the second will return:

```
Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check value in `$term` that should be greater then 3 in case of FULLTEXT index  search otherwise it will return null

The minimum and maximum lengths of words to be indexed are defined by the `ft_min_word_len` and `ft_max_word_len` system variables.  The default minimum value is four characters. If you change either value, you must rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes. For example, if you want three-character words to be searchable, you can set the ft_min_word_len variable by putting the following lines in an option file:

Answer (score 0):

`match()` only works on field which have a FULLTEXT on them, exactly as the error message says. You'd have to do:

```
ALTER TABLE blogs ADD FULLTEXT INDEX tituolo_ft (titulo);
```

before you can use fulltext operations on the field.

Comment: so can i improve the LIKE results quality?

Comment: depends on what you're searching for. fulltext indexes have higher maintenance overhead, but at least you CAN use indexes, whereas a `LIKE '%...%'` type search can  NOT ever use indexes.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message implies, you can't use `MATCH ... AGAINST` unless there is a *FULLTEXT* index on the field you are comparing.

The `LIKE` statement should work though. I think the problem may be the double quotes in your pattern which are superfluous and will require corresponding quotes in the database value. Please show what database data you are trying to match.

Comment: the rows are just plane strings, title of blog entries.. and $term would be like 'how to bla' or 'nice templates'

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the FULLTEXT index mentioned by others it looks like you are not properly quoting your text in the AGAINST clause. I think it should be:

```
AGAINST ('".$term."')
```

Or else, since you already have double quotes around your query just embed the variable:

```
AGAINST ('$term')
```